# How to create subquery in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am very new to **postgresql**. I have this table.

[image]

From this table I want the data like

```
region                country          count
---------------------------------------------------
UttarPradesh           India              16
California            United State        2
```

How to achieve this task. I did something but not properly end with the solution
here is my queries

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 AS
    (SELECT distinct region_name, country_name,  null::integer as "count"
     from opens where track_id=42);
```

After this I read this result then in a loop run update query with select statement.

So it is a right way ? Or any another way to achieve this task ?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why a subquery or temp tables, why not just

```
SELECT region_name, country_name, COUNT(*) 
FROM opens WHERE track_id = 42 GROUP by region_name, country_name
```

It's extremely rare in postgresql to have to use a temporary table. If you want to update this or another table with this data, you can easily do so with a well thought out query. Looping is equally undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT region_name, country_name, COUNT(*)
FROM t GROUP BY region_name, country_name
```